# How to generate Domino dialogboxes on traditional (non-xpages) webforms

Tags: lotus-domino

I want to have a popup/dialogbox with an "OK" button on it that will close the dialogbox...after someone performs a task on a Domino webform.   I know I used overlays in xpages before, but the current application I am maintaining was built with traditional Domino forms (lots of pass-thru HTML) and my initial attempt to build an overlay effect did not work.

I have tried using javascript code of:

```
var window = window.open(url, windowName, [windowFeatures]);
```

...but this has not been successful.  No errors in debug, yet my url page does not pop up.  I am hoping someone might be able to provide a snippet of what you use so I can see where I am going wrong.

The url parameter I am passing is correct, as I used an alert to show me what was going in there, but I am doing something basic wrong.

If I can answer any questions for you I can do that as well.

Thank you

Comment: Do you have a popup blocker enabled in the browser?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know to display a dialog box in a classic Domino web application is to do just like you would on any HTML-based webpage. Either you create your own popup functionality, or you use one of the many plugins available.
When I work with classic Domino web applications, I have often added Bootstrap to it, to make things look a bit better. Then I can use either the native Bootstrap dialog boxes, or a plug-in called [Bootbox.js](http://bootboxjs.com/). But there are many other ones.